# Div's moving with scroll

Tags: css

I'm looking for a solution, which let me make a Div's moving with scroll. I would like to make it like on picture below:

[image]

So Box 1 and Box 2 are Div's which moving with scroll within a Div1/Div2 area. The Footer is a limiter. If we have a very high footer - Box 1 and Box 2 stay at the end of Div1/Div2 area.

I would also like to on mobile devices these items are not moving but are static.

Thanks in advance,
Best Regards,
D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`position:sticky` will do this

> one link among others http://www.sitepoint.com/css-position-sticky-introduction-polyfills/
>
> mobile ? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

```css
div {
 display:flex;
}
aside, main, footer, div div {
  border:solid;
  flex:1;
  margin:5px;
}
main {
  min-width:60%;
  min-height:90vh
}
footer {
  height:40vh;
}
aside div {
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
  height:60vh
}
.bgr {
  height:70vh;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <aside>
  <div> sticky</div>
</aside>
<main> main</main>
<aside>
  <div class="bgr"> sticky</div>
</aside>
</div>
<footer>
  footer
</footer>
```